# How can I accept arguments from the command line?

Tags: perl, argv

I am writing a program where I have to input the file name, protein name, protein chains (A and B) and threshold value directly from command line. How can I use ARGV for this?  I want to provide the input arguments on the command line as follows:

```
perl file.pl 2hhb A B 7
```

Comment: By the way, if your question is `How can I use ARGV?`, your title `Perl Program: I am dealing with a PDB file` is rather... a strange choice.

Comment: `@ARGV` is an array. See `perldoc -v @ARGV`. If you are asking for help on how to use an array, I think your question is probably a bit too basic.

Comment: Why did you show the content of the file when your question is about how to "input the file name, protein name, protein chains(A and B) and threshold value directly from command line"?

Answer (score 3):

`ARGV` is the special file handle used by `<>`. (`<>` is short for `<ARGV>`.) The parameters are provided in `@ARGV`. In your example, `@ARGV` will be initialized by Perl as if with `@ARGV = ('2hhb', 'A', 'B', '7');`.

```
@ARGV == 5
   or die("Wrong number of command line arugments\n");

my ($pdp_qfn, $protein_name, $chain1, $chain2, $threshold) = @ARGV;
```

Note that you forgot to provide a file name in your example.